# Hermitian Matrix is complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If M is an nxn complex matrix with $M^T = M^*$, then M is Hermitian.

So, I know that an nxn complex matrix is called hermitian iff $M^H$=M. 
And $(M^T)^* = (M^*)^T = M^H$, so does this imply that the question above is true that $M^T = M^*$? No other proof to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Take the transpose of both sides of $$M^T = M^*.$$ (Caution: Sometimes $A^*$ itself is used to denote the conjugate transpose of $A$, in which case the conjugate of $A$ is usually denoted $\bar{A}$.)

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative hint:** if $M$ is Hermitian, then $M^* = (M^H)^*$